# Opening a Powerpoint presentation, Saving as PDF and closing the application using WIN32APIs

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32

I have written a small script to open a powerpoint file, save it as PDF and close powerpoint. It looks like the command ppSaveAsPDF is not getting recognized.

It says `NameError: name 'ppSaveAsPDF' is not defined`

Could someone please tell me why I am unable to save the file as pdf and close the application ?

Moreover when I remove the ppSaveAsPDF command it saves a PDF file but it is corrupt and I am unable to open it.

I have included my code below:

```
import win32com.client, sys    

FILENAME = "C:\\Users\\Swaroop\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Test.pptx"   
APPLICATION = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")    

PRESENTATION = APPLICATION.Presentations.Open(FILENAME, ReadOnly= False)
PRESENTATION.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\Swaroop\\Desktop\\Output.pdf",  ppSaveAsPDF)   

APPLICATION.Quit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have come up with a work around for this, instead of using ppSaveAsPDF, I am using its constant value which is "32" and setting both PRESENTATION AND APPLICATION to NONE actually closes the powerpoint. Here is the updated code.

```
import win32com.client, sys

FILENAME = "C:\\Users\\Swaroop\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Test.pptx"

APPLICATION = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")

PRESENTATION = APPLICATION.Presentations.Open(FILENAME, ReadOnly= False)
PRESENTATION.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\Swaroop\\Desktop\\Output.pdf", 32)

APPLICATION.Quit()

PRESENTATION =  None
APPLICATION = None
```

Answer (score 0):

The **ppSaveAsPDF** attribute can be accessed with:

```
win32com.client.constants.ppSaveAsPDF
```

Its value happens to be 32.

The full code line would look like this:

```
PRESENTATION.SaveAs("C:\\...\Output.pdf", win32com.client.constants.ppSaveAsPDF)
```